# Filereader null declarations and appending best practice

Tags: java, loops, exception, filereader, stringbuffer

I want to optimise my file reader function but am not sure if it is best practice to declare the nulls outside of the try loop. Also, is looping and appending chars to a Stringbuffer considered bad practice? I would like to use the exception handling here, but maybe it is better to use another structure? any advice most welcome, thanks.

```
public String readFile(){
File f = null;
FileReader fr = null;
StringBuffer content = null;
try{
f = new File("c:/test.txt");
fr = new FileReader(f);
int c;          
while((c = fr.read()) != -1){               
if(content == null){
content = new StringBuffer();
}

content.append((char)c);
        }

fr.close();         
    }
catch (Exception e) {
throw new RuntimeException("An error occured reading your file");
    }       
    return content.toString();
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Advice:

1. Indent your code properly.  The stuff in your question looks like a dog's breakfast.
2. You don't need to initialize `f` inside the try / catch block.  The constructor can't throw an `Exception` the way you are using it.
3. In fact, you don't need to declare it at all.  Just inline the `new File(...)`.
4. In fact, you don't even need to do that.  Use the `FileReader(String)` constructor.
5. There's no point initializing the `StringBuffer` inside the loop.  The potential performance benefit is small and only applies in the edge-case where the file is empty or doesn't exist.  In all other cases, this is an anti-optimization.
6. Don't catch `Exception`.  Catch the exceptions that you expect to be thrown and allow all other exceptions to propagate.  The unexpected exceptions are going to be due to bugs in your program, and need to be handled differently from others.
7. When you catch an exception, don't throw away the evidence.  For an unexpected exception, either print / log the exception, its message and its stacktrace, or pass it as the 'cause' of the exception that you throw.
8. The `FileReader` should be closed in a `finally` clause.  In your version of the code, the `FileReader` won't be closed if there is an exception after the object has been created and before the `close()` call.  That will result in a leaked file descriptor and *could* cause problems later in your application.
9. Better yet, use the new Java 7 "try with resource" syntax which takes care of closing the "resource" automatically (see below).
10. You are reading from the file one character at a time.  This is **very** inefficient.  You need to either wrap the `Reader` in a `BufferedReader`, or read a large number of characters at a time using (for example) `read(char[], int, int)`
11. Use `StringBuilder` rather than `StringBuffer` ... unless you *need* a thread-safe string assembler.
12. Wrapping exceptions in `RuntimeException` is bad practice.  It makes it difficult for the caller to handle specific exceptions ... if it needs to ... and even makes printing of a decent diagnostic more difficult.  (And that assumes that you didn't throw away the original exception like your code does.)

Note: if you follow the advice of point 8 and not 9, you will find that the initialization of `fr` to `null` is necessary if you open the file in the `try` block.

---

Here's how I'd write this:

```
public String readFile() throws IOException {
  // Using the Java 7 "try with resource syntax".
  try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("c:/test.txt")) {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
    int c;          
    while ((c = br.read()) != -1) {               
      content.append((char)c);
    }
    return content.toString();
  }
}
```

A further optimization would be to use `File.length()` to find out what the file size (in bytes) is and use that as the initial size of the `StringBuilder`.  However, if the files are typically small this is likely to make the application slower.

Comment: `try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("c:/test.txt"))` Is this legal in Java? Try without Catch? Try with parameters? Also, why are you throwing IOException if you have a try/catch block? Finally, content is out of scope when you return it.

Comment: It is legal in Java 7 syntax. This would not work in Java 6 or earlier. See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: @RyanAmos - 1) Yes it is legal Java 7 syntax.  2)  Yes, try without catch is legal ... see 1).  3) Yes, see 1).  4) because I'm NOT catching IOException.  5) Ooops ... I'll fix that.

Comment: @StephenC That's pretty cool. I haven't seen that... you learn something new every day, eh? +1

Answer (score 0):

```
public String readFile() {
    File f = new File("/Users/Guest/Documents/workspace/Project/src/test.txt");
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();;
    try {
        fr = new FileReader(f);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        //int c;
        //while ((c = fr.read()) != -1) {
            //content.append((char) c);
        //}
        String line = null;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            content.append(line);
        }
        fr.close();
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // do something

    }
    return content.toString();
}
```

Use buffered reader and youll get 70%+ improvement, use string builder instead of string buffer unless you need syncronization.

ran it on a 10MB file 50 times and averaged

- no need to put anything that does not need exception handling inside try
- no need for that if clause because it will be true only once and so you're wasting time - checking it for every character
- there is no runtime exceptions to throw.

results:
fastest combination to slowest:

1. string builder and buffered reader line by line: 211 ms
2. string buffer and buffered reader line by line: 213 ms
3. string builder and buffered reader char by char: 348 ms
4. string buffer and buffered reader char by char: 372 ms
5. string builder and file reader char by char: 878
6. string buffer and file reader char by char: 935 ms
7. string: extremely slow

so use string builder + buffered reader and make it read line by line for best results.

Comment: @StephenC, agreed! left it there from testing wrong file path :)